# How do I get json string from json?callback?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

How do I get the json string when provided only with a url?

I have a url provided:

https://example.com/something.json?callback=getAppData

which I use as such:

```
<script src="https://example.com/something.json?callback=getAppData"></script>
<script src="appData.js"></script>
```

appData.js:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log('appData');
    var data = getAppData();
    console.log(data);
}, false);
```

This logs nothing obviously.  How do I get the json data?  I am not using jQuery and this is a node.js app with mongoose.

Any direction is as always greatly appreciated, so thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `appData` file should be loaded before the JSONP request, and should have a function called `getAppData` in it. Inside that function, you'll have access to the JSON returned

Comment: Sketchy link you provided, I have to say..

Comment: It's a simple link that contains sensitive material which I would prefer to keep that way, so it's obviously not the actual link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the JSONP request is made, it will call the passed callback function, which will need to be defined by you. This function will receive the data.

```
<script>
    function getAppData(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
</script>
<script src="https://example.com/something.json?callback=getAppData"></script>
```

Usually you would add the `<script>` tag programatically, so you can make the call whenever you want.

Comment: Im going to accept this as it makes the most sense,  but also ask: add script dynamically?  Can I not add it via load or ready within appData.js?  I only need it initially and then Ill add apis to it as needed.

Comment: This is still not logging anything for data, but I will check and see if it is the provided string that is incorrect.  Wouldnt I get something in the log even if the string was empty, or would it just blank?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about node.js but here is the example for how to get JSON and JSONP value from the server.[example](http://koushiksite.blogspot.in)

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log('appData');
    var data = this.responseData["DATA"];
    console.log(data);
}, false);
```

or `var data = xhr.responseText;`?